# Create instance of generic class by reflection

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to use reflection to create an instance of a generic class.

For example, how to create an instance of `PriorityQueue<Integer>` using reflection such as Class or Type, instead of call its constructor.

Comment: Yes, you just create a raw instance of the class, and cast it. There is no difference between the two, owing to type erasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always cast raw types to/from generic types.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = (PriorityQueue<Integer>) PriorityQueue.class.newInstance();
```